# Source image upload location for Krea Content Elements

Tags: content-elements

I'm using Content Elements and would like to have some control over the file upload folder which a content elements gallery field is associated with. Is this even possible? Seems like a bit of an oversight if not... :/

Comment: I know this is an old post but I'd love to be able to choose Assets as the uploader